# Monitor suddenly does not allow native resolution

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

After a reboot my 2nd monitor is screwed up and I have no idea why. Native resolution is 1680x1050 which always worked. Now it displays a lower resolution and I found the message in the setting panel saying "The resolution is lower than 1440x1080. Blah blah..." Anyone knows what might be the root cause or how to solve this? Graphics card is a nvida gtx 1060. Already made a driver update with no effect. OS is Win 8.1 x64.

[image]

Comment: The times I've observed this, it usually meant the monitor itself was failing in some way. Before you assume the monitor is bad, though, check the display cables, try different cables, go into your Device Manager and delete any monitors listed there.

Comment: This happened to me recently with a DVI cable attached to a docking station. Amazing, simply unplugging and reattaching the cable to the dock fixed the problem.